# SQL Server - how to tie origin with correct destination/date?

Tags: sql-server

Apologies if something like this was answered, but I'm not seeing it. This is SQL Server. I'm looking at a list of trucks with unique identifiers (Unique ID). They go to various cities. They arrive (ArrivalDate) in the City (City) and then leave (SentDate). There is no destination column. The movement column is a sort of unique identifier for the movement; the first part is the UniqueID but the second is nothing.

| UniqueID | City | ArrivalDate | SentDate | Movement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 97841 | Los Angeles North | 25/01/2021 | 27/01/2021 | 97841 : 949814 |
| 93621 | Baltimore | 21/01/2021 | 22/01/2021 | 93621 : 646946 |
| 96872 | Los Angeles South | 19/01/2021 | 19/01/2021 | 96872 : 685469 |
| 97842 | Boston | 12/12/2020 | 20/12/2020 | 97841 : 646488 |

I'd like to write a query that shows a Unique ID that leaves from a particular city and goes to another. So, it would look something like this:

| UniqueID | City 1 | City 2 | SentDate | ArrivalDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 97841 | Los Angeles South | Boston | 12/12/2020 | 15/12/2020 |
| 97841 | Los Angeles North | Boston | 01/01/2021 | 05/01/2021 |

I run the code below. I'm using Inner Join on the same table to filter on the UniqueID. I get the right UniqueID, right cities. But obviously the dates aren't linking right. I'm getting valid dates for the cities, but they are out of order/whack. As in sure, the truck arrived in Boston but it's a date for six months later, when it should've been the showing proper arrival date of 4 or 5 days later. Any ideas for the right solutions for this? Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    aa.UniqueID,
    aa.City AS 'City 1', 
    bb.City AS 'City 2', 
    aa.SentDate,  
    bb.ArrivalDate      
FROM Movedata aa
INNER JOIN Movedata bb on bb.UniqueID = aa.UniqueID
WHERE (aa.City LIKE '%Los Angeles South%' AND bb.City LIKE '%Los Angeles North%') AND 
        (aa.SentDate < bb.ArrivalDate) AND 
        aa.SentDate BETWEEN '2020-01-28 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-01-29 00:00:00.000' 
ORDER by aa.SentDate DESC;
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Glad you provided example data but sorry to say I couldn't relate your example output with the given data set. Please elaborate how the example input match with output.

Comment: You have UK date formats and if you are in the US, that would explain the issue with the dates. Also your join would never produce what you need because the join values don't exist. Your approach would be correct if you had any matching values. All you would ever get would be Los Angeles North for City1 and City2 for example

Comment: Thanks Chuma, you're right, appreciated.